# Failed to import bean definitions from URL location

Tags: java, spring-mvc

estoy creando un proyecto con spring-mvc y MongoDB, cuando arranco el servidor Tomcat desde Eclipse me da el siguiente error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
>   Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL
>   location [classpath:core.xml]
>
> Offending resource: ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
>   to read candidate component class: file
>   [F:\Programas\Programacion\apache-tomcat-8.5.16\wtpwebapps\SpringMongo\WEB-INF\classes\es\arf\controller\NavigationController.class];
>   nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class
>   org.springframework.core.type.classreading.ClassMetadataReadingVisitor
>   has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class

este es mi fichero spring-servlet.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<import resource="classpath:core.xml"/>

<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

este es mi fichero core.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="es.arf" />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:appcore.properties"/>

<mongo:db-factory    id="mongoDbFactory" dbname="${mongo.database}" host="${mongo.host}" port="${mongo.port}"/>
<mongo:repositories base-package="es.arf"/>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
</bean>


<!-- on startup context execute changesets if needed -->
<!-- 
<mongo:mongo id="mongo" host="${mongo.host}" port="${mongo.port}"/>
<bean id="mongeez" class="org.mongeez.MongeezRunner">    
    <property name="mongo" ref="mongo"/>
    <property name="executeEnabled" value="${executeMigrations}"/>
    <property name="dbName" value="${mongo.database}"/>
    <property name="file" value="classpath:/changeSets/mongeez.xml"/>           
</bean>
-->
    </beans>
```

Estaría encantado de recibir vuestra ayuda.

Gracias

Comment: Esta pregunta es totalmente válida para el formato del sitio. No entiendo porque se reporta que debe ser cerrada como un error tipográfico.

Answer (score 1):

Tal y como indican [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40885319/1820254), el problema parece que lo tienes en que estás importando un jar de spring-asm que ya no es necesario porque ya está incluido en el core de spring y eso hace que haya un conflicto de versiones.

Revisa lo de esa respuesta y, si sigue sin funcionarte, comenta si el proyecto lo has construido con Maven o Gradle y comparte el pom.xml o el build.gradle. Si lo estás haciendo a pelo, comparte el listado de jars que estás vinculando a tu proyecto.

Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta.